# MySQL 5.7.9 passwordless zip install

Tags: mysql

So mysql 5.7.9 defaults with no data-directory, this means we are unzipping and running (i'm using non standard data-dir):

> mysqld --initialize --datadir=c:\somedir\data\mysql_data

dont't forget updating my.ini when using non standard data directory: datadir=C:\somedir\data\mysql_data

Normally I change my root password by running:

> mysqladmin -u root -p password PASSWORD

MySQL however creates a temp rootpassword (from err):

> 2015-11-12T14:40:59.039400Z 1 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: YFpOlBnGk4%f

Can I force mysql not to create this password?

EDIT#2

After re-thinking my conclusion is that the approach I want is wrong. Before MySQL version 5.7.6, a pre-installed database with blank password was shipped with the server. What I wanted is to generate a database without root password, but why? Nothing prevents me from generating my own database and shipping this in my own zip-install (just like pre 5.7.6) - which solves my problem.

Comment: Try start without `--skip-grant-tables` and run from cmd line `mysqladmin -uroot password _yourpassword_`

Comment: This won't work, running mysqld --initial set's a password to the root user (which I don't want). I'm updating my post with a simple solution that works for me.

Comment: Hmm root without password is bad idea...

Comment: Mysql prior version 5.7.6 actually got shipped with a database containing root user with blank password. Yes is it bad practice, but in my commandline-script I unzip MySQL, create databases, set user(s) and update root password. My script broke with this new MySQL version as I cannot login anymore (I first need to get password out of error file).